# Upgrade 22.10 to 23.04 one area is not clickable

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 I have this area (red rectangle) not clickable in any applications. Moreover, When I click minimize, some applications from the tray panel are called.

[image: Screenshot]

[UPDATE]

After running this command `setsid gnome-shell --replace` I saw this area in gray. After this problem was solved, but after reboot it appeared again.

[image: Screenshot]

Also, it seems like this area is a tray application because it is showing the name of the application from the tray.

[UPDATE #2]

Found out that this window is an invisible application icon. When I change workspace it becomes visible.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLHsBJe1kv76ijC0-1dXnUGyEuwz2LO8/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Try to disable all GNOME addons and test again after rebooting.

Comment: After disabling "Ubuntu Appindicators" and rebooting, that area is clickable. So it might be something with this extension

Comment: I tried to use other extensions for tray applications, but they have the same problem

Comment: File a bugreport if the extension is supposed to work with your version of gnome Otherwise ask for  an upgrade of the extension. We can not do much about this unless the maintainer of that extension is on AU and that is unlikely. Most of them use github as a bug report medium

Comment: Solution for minimize, restore and close - [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464947/ubuntu-23-04-close-not-working/1467275#1467275](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464947/ubuntu-23-04-close-not-working/1467275#1467275)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this is anydesk issue, after deleting anydesk, the problem was solved.