# Ubuntu 23.04 close not working

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, window-buttons, 23.04

I am unable to close programs on Ubuntu 23.04. I cannot see any change when hovering over the minimize, maximize and close buttons. When I try to click the close button nothing happens.

Here are my system's specs:

[image: Ubuntu version Image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's not the `close` button, its the top right corner below the bar,
if you move the window away so that the `close` button isn't on the top right corner, you will be able to click.

at the moment, I am able to click on the close, but not the maximize or minimize, when I click them another program will start, that program has an icon in the top bar, **I guess somehow clicking this area clicks on the top bar for some reason.**

**ANYDESk** is the reason, remove it and the problem is solved.
solution here : https://askubuntu.com/a/1464963/1690773

Comment: That is right, when the full screen

Comment: Uninstalling Anydesk fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoting because uninstalling Anydesk is not really a fix. The other answer works for me.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because of legacy tray icon's size, you have to disable 'Legacy Tray Icon support' until the bug fix.

1. open gnome extensions from terminal with the command `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`
2. Click settings of "Ubuntu AppIndicators"
   [image: gnome-shell-extension-prefs]
3. In "Ubuntu AppIndicators" settings window, toggle off "Enable Legacy Tray Icons Support"
   [image: Ubuntu AppIndicators Settings]

4. Log Out and Log In

Comment: Didn't work on Goolge chrome

Comment: It Worked For Me. Thank YOU ^_^