# Dead zone on desktop after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, window

After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 I've got a dead zone in the top right of my desktop. If I put a GNOME window over the area it works fine, but if I put any other window (browser, game, anything) it effectively goes under it and that area in the window becomes unclickable.

I've tried killing processes in the task bar in case it was them causing a window or menu, but no deal. Tried both X and Wayland. Still there.

I've seen a couple of mentions on here of a similar thing way back in 11.xx with Unity.

The dead zone only shows when I switch between desktops.

[image: The dead zone only shows when I switch between desktops]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade 22.10 to 23.04 one area is not clickable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464483/upgrade-22-10-to-23-04-one-area-is-not-clickable)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be something to do with Anydesk. Even closing it down keeps the invisible window/menu going. Only way I've found round this is to uninstall Anydesk as there doesn't seem to be an option to NOT have it start on startup. I'll contact Anydesk.

Comment: It's not just Anydesk. Google Chrome does it, so does hexchat. It's unclear why 1 type of window has the issue while another does not.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this issue after upgrading to 23.04.  It was definitely Anydesk causing the problem.  Uninstalling Anydesk and rebooting has solved it.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me too. It is a shame, because anydesk works so well. FWIW I had to reboot for the dead zone to go away.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of legacy tray icon's size. Therefore the (temporary) solution is to disable the same until the bug is fixed.

Steps:

1. Open Extension Manager application (search for the same in Apps or use `extension-manager` command).
2. Click settings of "Ubuntu AppIndicators".
3. Toggle off "Enable Legacy Tray Icons Support".
4. Log out and Log in.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same issue with non clickable deadzone in the same spot right after upgrading to 23.04.
Deactivated Gnome extension "Ubuntu AppIndicators" (as suggested in the linked article above) and now the deadspot is gone.

BTW, I use Anydesk and it is still installed but doesn't cause a deadspot in my case.

Update: problem is back again, comes and goes, might be Anydesk